# Ajax success function not triggering

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm trying to execute an alert after ajax post is triggered, i'm using the next script for the ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.sbmIngresoGrupo').on('click', function () {
    var Tipo = $('.Tipo').val();
    var Categoria = $('.Categoria').val();
    var Monto = $('#Monto').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("AgregarGrupo", "AjaxPosts")",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({
            Tipo: Tipo,
            Categoria: Categoria,
            Monto: Monto
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            alert('Funciono');
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('No se insertaron los datos deseados.');
        }
    });
});
```

my controller is the next:

```
public IActionResult AgregarGrupo([FromBody] GruposKm gruposKm, ConexionDB _conexion)
    {
        #region Data

        gruposKm.Activo = "S";
        gruposKm.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
        gruposKm.Responsable = HttpContext.Session.GetString("User");
        gruposKm.Codigo = "Código";
        #endregion

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_conexion.Chain("", "")))
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[PCK].[P_INSERT_GRUPO_KM]", conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CODIGO",gruposKm.Codigo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TIPO", gruposKm.Tipo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORIA", gruposKm.Categoria);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MONTO", gruposKm.Monto);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACTIVO", gruposKm.Activo);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RESPONSABLE", gruposKm.Responsable);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error {1}: " + ex);
                        throw;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error {0}: " + ex);
                throw;
            }
        }

        List<GruposKm> lista = new List<GruposKm>();
        lista.Add(gruposKm);
        return new JsonResult(lista);
    }
```

The problem here is that when the the ajax action executes, the success function is not triggering, it is very weird cause with the same code the first times it worked perfect, but now it is not working anymore

Comment: You mean that the code you have worked before but could not work now?I test your code and could trigger success function.Did you do any other operation with the code?I suggest that you could set breakpoints to debug the action if it makes error.Also provide your whole view and model would better for reproducing your issue.

Comment: yes, I mean that the code was working fine just before, but it suddenly stopped triggering the success function, i'm gonna try to debug at chrome debugger, thanks